# EJB 2.0 - straighting it out for me

Tags: ejb

I am working with EJB 2.0.

I have some gaps. mind helpoing me fill them?

A. when I creat an EJB project and write my code, I need to perform rmic. Then these generated files - I put them also in my client side?

B. I once heard of a phrase "skeleton" vs. "stub" - could you tell which is each.

B. Also, I have a project and I want to deploy it. I understand I need to create an EAR project automatically out of my EJB project. What do I need to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here mentioned abstract purpose of each, but if you want to get more information on that, go through RMI documention.

- **Stub** : A stub for a remote object acts as a client's local representative or proxy for the remote object.
- **Skeleton** : The skeleton is responsible for dispatching the call to the actual remote object implementation. They are eliminated since version 1.2.

You can use build tool like Maven/ANT to build EAR project out of EJB project.

They can also be used to build client-side jars, so you don't have to manually look after generating them using rmic.